# Reading a configuration file in c#

Tags: c#, .net

The configuration file of my app is similar to,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Items>
      <Item Name="Coffee"
            Cost="10"
            Image="itemCoffee.png" />
      <Item Name="Tea"
            Cost="10"
            Image="itemTea.png" />
      <Item Name="Vada"
            Cost="10"
            Image="itemVada.png" />
  </Items>
```

Just trying to read the above small configuration file and I wrote this method.

```
public static class Configuration
{
    public static T DeSerialize<T>(string filePath)
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException(filePath);
        }

        var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(T);
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open));
    }
}
```

1. Where should I use `using` in this code? (Because, I never ever dispose the `new FileStream` that I wrote in this method)
2. Is this an overkill for reading this simple xml file?

Comment: If that XML is really the *configuration file of your app*, I think you've missed an opportunity to leverage [*.net application settings*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I would definitely wrap the FileStream object into a using clause like this:

   ```
   using (Stream reader = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
   {
     var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
     return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
   }
   ```

   This way the Dispose method of the `FileStream` gets called immediately. Otherwise it will be delayed until the `FileStream` object gets garbage collected. This may not be a big problem in practice in simple applications where you read the configuration only once but is good practice to do it anyway.
   Also note that you have to use `XmlSerializer(typeof(T))` instead of `XmlSerializer(T)`.
2. My opinion is that it is overkill to create a generic method if you have only one kind of configuration file in your app. This method might be hard to read for a maintainer who is not sufficiently comfortable with generics and it has no benefit in making your code DRY-er if you have only one type of configuration file.

Comment: I agree on your first point, but not on your second. I do not think it's overkill to create a generic method for this. If there are any programmers in the wild that do not understand generics they shouldn't be working as programmers. And by making a generic method he will be able to reuse his method whenever he needs it - whether its today or tomorrow or months from now.

Comment: @Andris: Thank you. `I prefer Answer for point 1` and go with @Max's comment for `Point 2`. Thanks.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. Point 2 is a judgement call. It is quite readable but it still feels like YAGNI to me.

Comment: YAGNI and DRY are sometimes at odds. Particularly here where the required effort to create the generic is almost nothing, and the chances of reusing the method are high.